# Copy file from One Zone to Other - Azure Data Lake Gen2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I want to copy a file with given path from One Zone of Azure Data Lake to Other Zone of Data Lake.

**Example:**

**Source**: /RawZone/Incremental/2020/05/01/file.parquet

**Destination**: /StdZone/Incremental/2020/05/01/file.parquet

Should i be using Copy Activity to read source as dataset and write to Destination.  Or is there a way to just copy file from source to destination in **Azure Data Factory**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware the Copy Activity is the only way.

You will need a dataset to define where the file is coming from and going (though the path can be parameterised) and its format.

If you want to copy the file as is without alteration, set the dataset format to `binary` to avoid having to define the file structure and 'waste time' extracting and parsing the data within.